# How to show large of data to user in dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

I have a website that show the user large of theater name.
What is the best way to show them with less scroll or user click?
I mean when user select the button to see all of theater name , all of them (for example 500 theater) display for users.
At first i put drop down list,but now this is not nice ,so help me to choose best and nice object to show my data(theater name +"   " + Director: this is my important data to show to user at first).

> Note :after user select her-his theater then want to select the sans number, in first version of my website,first user click on combo box and select the theater name then in second combo box the sans number and the time and price of ticket load in telerik coxcomb and display it to user as a grid view(table in Rad combo box).but i want to change this style and make it modern and so nice.But i don't know HOW?

Comment: You can populate your dropdown dynamically when your user types. Or you can add a previous dropdown allowing to filter theaters by City. If your users often use the same theaters you can allow them to mark them as favourites

Comment: use other kind of control.

Comment: Is it necesary to use dropdown contro.Can you allowed to use other control?

Comment: yes, i just look for a control to show my data to users in nice and simple way to select her-his theater.But i don't know which control is good for this?

Comment: Perhaps this jQuery plugin solves your problem completely client side. Just populate your large dropdown. pull in jquery from a cdn and then use this jquery plugin http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ or you can populate a nested dataset as json and use jQuery to build a 2nd level option list http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/T7LJY/3/

Comment: thank you for your response, I saw this [page](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)about drop down i had a drop down to show data like this(it was telerik)Suppose you have 10 theaters and the displayed to user in two columns (5 item left side five item right side like table).I search for better solution and if drop down is best answer so i think a drop down like this telerik is better.But i don not know how to create a control like tererik combo box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML `select` elements really fail in usability when lists are too long; I would recommend you using a jQuery plugin instead to improve the usability of that particular feature of your site. Your users would be better off with an auto-complete plugin to allow them to search more efficiently the options available.

I have personally used [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) for this kind of features and it has proved to be really useful. Using this plugin (or almost any other popular auto-complete plugin out there) will allow you to easily implement features like: remote searches (using server-side logic), result templating, result grouping and others.

Answer (score 0):

jQueryUI Autocomplete with a dropdown is probably what you looking for 
[JQuery Autocomplete with dropdown](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)